# IE8 displays legend in blue but all other browsers dispaly it correctly in white text. Why?

Tags: joomla, legend, internet-explorer-8

I have a Joomla 1.5 site with a client login on the page (rather than going right into the back-end) using the standard Joomla module, but when the login is accessed via IE* the  tag displays in blue. It is set in the .css files as white. IE8 is ignoring this. Any ideas? This only shows when admin is logged in so hard to show the problem without setting a temporary password (thus giving the whole world access to the site-don't really want to do that!)

Comment: can u debg using debugbar in ie that what composite style is applied on your element; this may give you a hint of whats going wrong with ie

Comment: Yes I did that in Firebug in Firefox and with IE Developer Toolbar in ie8 (the page in firefox is fine but firebug is the preferred tool for me). It just says <legend> then puts the text in that goes blue followed by the closing legen tag.